# Is it possible to redirect non-WebKit user agents to specific page by nginx?

Tags: nginx, browser-detection

I need to redirect users to specific page if their user-agent is not WebKit family. Is it possible to do by using nginx?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but considering the number of sites that break because of bad detection of newer browsers, isn't [feature detection](http://modernizr.com/) a better way?

Comment: modernizr is client solution but I need server side one.

Comment: Yep, asking the client is the only way to know if the feature you need is available. Guessing by user agent isn't necessarily as specific, is the feature you need available in Safari 1.0 which is WebKit? :) Just mentioning it since I've had more than one site break that detects IE and fails on new IE for no reason due to changed UA.

Comment: I don't not plan to support non-WebKit browsers at all so I need to redirect users to specific page for downloading one of several WebKit browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the $http_user_agent variable to check against it

```
set $webkit_rewrite do_not_perform;

## http_user_agent for webkit ##
if ($http_user_agent ~* WebKit) {
  set $webkit_rewrite perform;
}

## redirect to webkit.example.com ##
if ($webkit_rewrite = perform) {
  rewrite ^ http://m.example.com$request_uri? redirect;
  break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it applies to new Opera also?

Comment: Yes, as it's based on WebKit. You can also add new user-agents by doing:

    if ($http_user_agent ~* "WebKit|MSIE|...") {

Comment: @Erik Yes, [these sample user agents](https://github.com/HaraldWalker/user-agent-utils/issues/14) should match.

Comment: Thanks and the last question is what user-agent has safari browser?

Comment: @Erik It should be listed in detail [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).